# Wumpuses: conditionals and matrices

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I am in the process of writing some CS notes. In tha regard I am trying to illustrate different wumpus worlds. One example is given below:

[image]

In particular I need subsets of these. Niw, I am not looking for a full solution, but some helpt getting started would be wonderful.

What I want to create is some command to generate the last two columns, excluding the breeze in (4,3). So

.......... (4,4)

(3,4) , (3,4)

(2,4) , (2,4)

(1,4) , (1,4)

I need to be able to specify whether each element contains:

*pit, breeze, stench, gold, wumpus, person* or *start*.

Again I am not looking for a fully fledged out solution, but I really do not know where to start. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: it's not clear what the issue is, can't you just use a 4-column `tabular` and use `\stench`, `\pit` etc in the cells and then just define each of these to include a picture, or draw something with tikz?

Comment: The problem occurs when there are multiple icons that need to occur in each of the boxes.

Comment: Some icons in your image (e.g. pit) more or less fill their box. What do you want to do if they occur in the same square as other icons?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar it still is completely unclear what you are asking, why not a row like `\stench&&\pit\smell&\gold\wumpus\\ ` which has 1,0,2,2 images per cell?

Comment: Can you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228)? In particular, how do you create the images and what are the rules for having multiple images in one cell? I can imagine a command that sets the grid size and then gives coordinates for the cells containing `PIT`, `breeze` etc but as I am not sure what you want...

Comment: You've tagged this `tikz-matrix` and `tikz-pgf`. Ti*k*Z is overkill, as David said, but, of course, you can use a Ti*k*Z matrix. But then, again, you just fill the nodes in the same way as you would the suggested tabular lines. Your question doesn't say anything about multiple icons in a box. But, in any case, if multiples are the problem, please post an MWE for the non-multiple case and show us how you are trying to add additional icons and what you don't like about the result.